# require_asset from parent app using file within an Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app that uses an engine "core."

Core has vendor/javascripts/filepicker_v1

I am overriding a rails_admin file from "app"

app/assets/javascripts/rails_admin/custom/ui.js.erb

`require_asset 'filepicker_v1'` inside of this file doesn't seem to load the file from the embedded engine.

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: have you tried putting the file in app/assets instead of vendor?

Answer (score 0):

```
//= require filepicker_v1
```

will work